# how to Pass data from dropdownlist to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime, ado.net

i want to pass the date from a three dropdownlists to database and i have faced a problem that is (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.) and i have declared datatype DateTime please answer me quickly ???

the code behind is

```
pi.p_date = new DateTime(int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_daydate.SelectedItem.Text),int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_monthdate.SelectedItem.Text) , int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_yeardate.SelectedItem.Text));
```

and the from is :

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="purchinvoice_dropdownlist_daydate" CssClass="dropdownliststyle" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>Day</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="purchinvoice_dropdownlist_monthdate" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownliststyle">
                <asp:ListItem>month</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="purchinvoice_dropdownlist_yeardate" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownliststyle">
                <asp:ListItem>Year</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2014</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2015</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2016</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2017</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2018</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2019</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2020</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2021</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2022</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2023</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2024</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2025</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

and the class is:

```
  public class purchinvoice
{
    public string purch_serial_number;
    public string sup_name;
    public DateTime p_date;

    public purchinvoice()
    {
        purch_serial_number = null;
        sup_name = null;
        p_date = new DateTime();
    }
    public bool add_purchinvoice(out string msg)
    {
        msg = "";
        bool b = true;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBconnection.connectstr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("add_purch_invoice", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add("@purch_serial_number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = this.purch_serial_number;
            com.Parameters.Add("@sup_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = this.sup_name;
            com.Parameters.Add("@p_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.p_date;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            b = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            b = false;
            msg = ex.Message;
            con.Close();

        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: where you are assigning day, month and year to p_date??

Comment: @Mohamed Yousri .. you are not assigning value to your p_date it is either empty or null you need to assign value

Comment: What are the value of your dropdownlist values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "DateTime.Parse".

```
    DateTime.Parse
    (
    purchinvoice_dropdownlist_monthdate.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + 
    purchinvoice_dropdownlist_daydate.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + 
    purchinvoice_dropdownlist_yeardate.SelectedItem.Text
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the DateTime constructor incorrectly.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is a DateTime Constructor overload that can take 3 parameters.
i.e.

```
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day)
```

You are passing the parameters in the wrong order.

Try changing your code behind to use this instead.

```
pi.p_date = new DateTime(
    int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_yeardate.SelectedItem.Text),        
    int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_monthdate.SelectedItem.Text),
    int.Parse(purchinvoice_dropdownlist_daydate.SelectedItem.Text) 
);
```

You should also probably make sure that the Text fields can actually be parsed to integers, otherwise you will still receive an exception if the user supplies invalid values.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code in the html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#TextBox3").datepicker({

                showOn: 'both',
                buttonText: 'Select',
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                chnageMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,

            });

        });

    </script>
```

And call the values from this code in C#:

```
string Issue_Date = TextBox3.Text;
DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Issue_Date);
Console.WriteLine( Date.Year + "" + Date.Month + "" + Date.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ASP.NET Calendar control instead. It will save you a lot of time.